# Get 403 error when attempting to access tomcat server. Work fine when accessing non https site

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ssl, tomcat7

We're currently looking to move our site to have it accessible only as https. I'm currently following the tutorial as found on http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html, generating a key and then un-commenting the SSL section of server.xml. This is what I used in that section to enable SSL.

```
 <Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8443" maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
         keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

I've also left the original settings that would allow access to the app via port 8080 as well.

When I attempt to access the application, http://localserver.com:8080 still works, but https://localserver.com:8443 returns a 403 error. Looking at the logs provides no answers as the log folder is empty of any files.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace or anything from the Tomcat logs? Would most likely be useful to see your configuration as well. There is not much to go off of the question currently.

Comment: I suspect your SSL is not configured correctly, but this is a guess until you post your logs.

Comment: @MikeKobit Sorry I'll flesh that question out a bit more. Did it while running to a meeting. Regarding your question about stack traces/log entries, I don't see anything saved in the log folders, which is bizarre.